# How to display data from django class methods in templates ?

Tags: django

I am trying to count the number of objects and display the number on my html page. I am planning to use this procedure for various calculations and filterings, so `{{ object_list.count }}` is not acceptable by me.

model

```
class Assets(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    serial = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.serial

    def totalAssets(self):
        totalAssets = self.all().count()
        return totalAssets
```

view

```
class AssetList(ListView):
    model = Assets
```

template

```
{{ object_list.totalAssets }}
```

What am I doing wrong ? The tag I am using shows no errors and no output at the same time.

Comment: `object_list` is a list of Asset objects, so it's like performing a `[asset1, asset2 ...].totalAssets` (which is incorrect). For the error part, most template tags fail silently in django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do something like:

```
{{ object_list.totalAssets }}
```

You are calling a **instance method** of a `QuerySet`. 
I don't know why you dont want to use `{{ object_list.count }}`, but you can add the count to the template context:

```
class AssetList(ListView):
    model = Assets

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(AssetList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['total_assets'] = self.model.objects.all().count()
        return context
```

and then in your template:

```
{{ total_assets }}
```

**EDIT**

```
class Assets(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    serial = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.serial

    @classmethod
    def total_assets(cls):
        return cls.objects.all().count()

class AssetList(ListView):
    model = Assets

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(AssetList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['total_assets'] = self.model.total_assets()
        return context
```

Comment: is it safe to do this as a context in views.py? I could prefer to accomplish it in a model class method.

Comment: but in model you MUST iterate to get the data from methods. So your approach might be the only one working.

Comment: and I am getting an error " type object 'Assets' has no attribute 'all' "

Comment: did you write `cls.all().count()` ? try just `cls.count()`

Comment: yes, I can't make it work. I get the same error. type object 'Assets' has no attribute 'count'

Comment: I tried with return cls.objects.all().count() and I believe it works

Comment: nope. Can you please correct it and I will accept your answer ?

Comment: OH! now i see the mistake. Sorry. yes,now i fix it

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the @property decorator to achieve this, although I've never tried it with a class method. To be honest, you might want a custom manager for this, the logic in the code above seems a bit wrong.

```
class Assets(models.Model):

    @property
    def totalAssets(self):
        return "blah"
```

Comment: Also, why are you manually creating the 'id' field? django should create this automatically for you, exactly as your code is doing.

Comment: you are right, it's possibly because I have too much to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that: totalAssets needs to be called by an object and not by a list ?

Comment: I believe all objects need to be iterated to return data - not quite sure about that.

Comment: What I mean is: in your template you have to call the method from one of your objects like this: {{ object_list.0.totalAssets }}. Also, you might need to change your model-method to: def totalAssets(self):
        totalAssets = Assets.objects.all().count()
        return totalAssets

Comment: if you need to have this data available in all your templates you could use a context processor.